# Python dict mapping from hindi characters to unicode characters

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, python-unicode, hindi, unicode-literals

Where can I get a Dictionary in python which contains mappings from Hindi characters to unicode characters? (Getting unicode characters corresponding to Hindi text character by character)

Comment: [does this helps?](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F)

Comment: Thanks, But i need them in python dictionary with vowels, consonants along with vowel diacritics, numerals , fractions and other symbols.